# MQTT Client Publisher Acknowledgement M2MTT Liberary Code

Tags: mqtt, publisher

I am using c# M2MQTT Client code to publish and subscribe the data. I have set the QOS Level 1 or 2. Do not know that how the publisher will get the notification when delivery completes. I have searched a lot on inter net but no code available. Please let me know if any one how to handle the acknowledgement at publisher end in c#.

```
MqttClient client = new MqttClient(IPAddress.Parse(mqttserverurl));
 clientId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
   client.Connect(clientId, uname, pwd);`enter code here`

   client.Publish("testtopic", Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Hi"), MqttMsgBase.QOS_LEVEL_EXACTLY_ONCE, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't.

It's all handled internally by the MQTT client library and M2MQTT doesn't seem to have a on_publish callback.

Comment: You mean no mqtt publisher client get notification on the delivered message in QOS1 or  QOS2 ???

Comment: I have seen your comment on this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37875962/acknowledgement-on-publish-mqtt Clearly you mention that most of the libraries support this callback. Can i get any c# library information where deliverycomplete callback support

Comment: I have situation where need to show logs to the client where all published messages are delivered ?

Comment: As I said, "most" in this case I can see no evidence that M2MQTT supports this feature.

Comment: Apologies to interrupt you but any other library or api supports same ?